# Different ways to install Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, usb, iso-image

Is there any way to install Win7 without CD or USB?
I don't want to burn iso file to CD. Can I use programs like power Iso?

Comment: It depends on the target system. Is it a virtual machine? Is it a laptop? When you ask if there is a program to install the answer would be "Technically yes" but considering the way you worded your question I would have to say no. WDS for PXe booting or other server that dishes out network deployment.

Comment: What’s wrong with a USB drive? Making it bootable is easy.

Comment: But can I return USB to previous condition after installation?

Comment: @user390214 - Sure; Just format the drive like normal;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you currently have an OS installed, you CAN install Windows 7 directly from an ISO file, you'll need a third-party tool if the current OS is Windows 7, whereas Windows 8 has this functionality built straight in.

As you asked, yes, you can return the USB to previous conditions after installation. Just make sure that you back up ALL your data on it, otherwise it will be lost when the drive is formatted!

Comment: I have windows XP. Can I install win7 from ISO?

Comment: Not entirely sure, however a tool like Daemon Tools Lite should allow you to access an ISO.

Comment: @user390214 - Just create a bootable disk;  Its far to complicate any other way for you.

Answer (score 1):

Technically yes, but for the purposes of your question the answer is no.

Unless you want to install your OS inside a Virtual Machine or you have a network boot/PXE boot environment set up (such as WDS, or some other TFTP PXE boot software) you will need to create a bootable USB/CD-ROM/DVD.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, you can install you OS directly from ISO file. First, decompress the ISO file to your computer and then you just click the "setup" to install OS to your computer. I have installed a Win 7 like this

Comment: This seems more like a comment than an answer.

Comment: But I have illustrated the process to install OS from ISO file directly. And which step I didn't explain clearly?

Comment: You don't seem positive you can even do this.  You don't tell the user how to decompress the .ISO to their computer.  Doing so wouldn't be installing the OS from the .ISO file but a local file located within the operating system itself which wouldn't work.